# Как запустить аргумент (объект) в DialogFragment, который открывается через coroutines EventChannel?

Tags: android, kotlin, dialogfragment, coroutine

Мне нужно, чтобы при долгом нажатии на recycler Item возникал диалог в посросом "уверены что удалить ...?" И после нажатия positiveButton объект Spend() удалялся из базы. Не пойму, как запустить в этот диалог объект, чтобы именно его удаление вызвать.

DoaligFragment:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class DeleteTransactionDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

    private val viewModel: DeleteTransactionViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog =
        AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
            .setTitle(requireContext().resources.getString(R.string.confirm_deletion))
            .setMessage(requireContext().resources.getString(R.string.really_delete_transaction))
            .setNegativeButton(requireContext().resources.getString(R.string.cancel_action), null)
            .setPositiveButton(requireContext().resources.getString(R.string.yes)) { _, _ ->
                viewModel.onConfirmClick(spend) // here I need to pass Spend() argument but how do I recieve it in the Fragment itself?
            }
            .create()
```

}

ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class DeleteTransactionViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repo: FinRepository,
    @ApplicationScope private val applicationScope: CoroutineScope
) : ViewModel() {

    fun onConfirmClick(spend: Spend) = applicationScope.launch {
        repo.deleteSpend(spend)
    }
}
```

RecyclerFragment:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class RecyclerTransactionsFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_transactions_recycler),
    RecyclerTransactionAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentTransactionsRecyclerBinding
    private val viewModel: RecyclerTransactionsViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
           //blablabla
        }

        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            viewModel.recTransEvent.collect {
                when (it) {
                    is RecyclerTransactionsViewModel.RecTransEvent.NavigateToDeleteTransactionScreen -> TODO()
                }.exhaustive
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onItemLongClick(spend: Spend) {
        viewModel.onTransactionLongTouched(spend)
    }
}
```

In RecyclerViewModel:

```
ViewModel() {

    private val recTransEventChannel = Channel<RecTransEvent>()
    val recTransEvent = recTransEventChannel.receiveAsFlow()

    //blablabla

    fun onTransactionLongTouched(spend: Spend) = viewModelScope.launch {
        recTransEventChannel.send(RecTransEvent.NavigateToDeleteTransactionScreen(spend))
    }

    sealed class RecTransEvent {
        data class NavigateToDeleteTransactionScreen(val spend: Spend) : RecTransEvent()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, отвечу сам, вдруг кому пригодится.

В файле навигации `nav_graph.xml` (у меня библиотека navigation components) я добавил свой `DeleteTransactionDialogFragment` в качестве new destination, и к нему добавил в `arguments` объект `Spend()` (который является `@Parcelable`).
И добавил к фрагменту `global atcion` чтобы можно было на него направлять навигацию.

И в основном фрагменте, там где я перебираю Event-ы из channel, запустил этот аргумент в открываемый диалог так:

```
                    is RecyclerTransactionsViewModel.RecTransEvent.NavigateToDeleteTransactionScreen -> {
                        val action = RecyclerTransactionsFragmentDirections.actionGlobalDeleteTransactionDialogFragment(it.spend)
                        findNavController().navigate(action)
                    }
```

А DeleteTransactionViewModel ловлю этот аргумент Spend в SavedStateHandle:

```
class DeleteTransactionViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repo: FinRepository,
    @ApplicationScope private val applicationScope: CoroutineScope,
    private val state: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {

    val spend = state.get<Spend>("spend")

    fun onConfirmClick(spend: Spend) = applicationScope.launch {
        repo.deleteSpend(spend)
    }
```

И в самом DeleteTransactionDalogFragment вызываю удаление так:

```
.setPositiveButton(requireContext().resources.getString(R.string.yes)) { _, _ ->
                if (viewModel.spend != null) {
                    viewModel.onConfirmClick(viewModel.spend!!)
                } else {
                    Timber.d("The Spend? id currently null")
                }
            }
```

Пока всё работает (и главное что при повороте экрана DialogFragment сохраняется, так как "живет" во `ViewModel`).